# How do I fix the error illegal return statement on line 62 in apps script?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a app in mit app inventor and the functionality of the app is to read and send data to google sheet. For that I have written a code in apps script but it shows that there is a illegal return statement on line 62 which has been highlighted-( if(getPWD==password){return ContentService.createTextOutput(getFullName);}  ). Please help on how to fix this.

Code:-
//**************************************************************************************

```
function doGet(e){
  return Authentication(e);
}

function doPost(e){
return Authentication(e);
}

function Authentication(e){
  
  if(e.parameter.func == "Create") {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ID);
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH);

    var rg = sh.getName() + "!" + sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
    var email = e.parameter.email;
    var sql = ' "Select B where B=\''+email+'\' " ';
    var qry = ' =IFERROR(query(' + rg + ',' + sql + '), "")';

    var ts = ss.insertSheet();
    var setQuery = ts.getRange(1,1).setFormula(qry);
    var getResult = ts.getDataRange().getValues();
    ss.deleteSheet(ts);
    
    if (getResult ==""){
    var data  = [e.parameter.fullname, e.parameter.email, e.parameter.password, e.parameter.phone];
    sh.appendRow(data);
    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(getResult);}
  } 
  
  
  
  
}
// ********************************************************************************************************



if(e.parameter.func == "Login") {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ID);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH);

  var email = e.parameter.email;
  var password = e.parameter.password;
  
  var rg = sh.getName() + "!" + sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  var sql = ' "Select A,B,C where B=\''+email+'\' " ';
  var qry = ' =IFERROR(query(' + rg + ',' + sql + '), "")';

  var ts = ss.insertSheet();
  var setQuery = ts.getRange(1,1).setFormula(qry);
  var getResult = ts.getDataRange().getValues();

  var getPWD = ts.getRange(1,3).getValues();
  var getFullName = ts.getRange(1,1).getValues();
  ss.deleteSheet();

    if(getResult!=""){
      if(getPWD==password){return ContentService.createTextOutput(getFullName);}
      else{ return ContentService.createTextOutput("ERPWD");}
    }
  else{return ContentService.createTextOutput(getResult);}
}
```

Comment: A `return` statement has to be inside of a function. The three down there are not. Fix your formatting so that you see where code blocks start and end.

Comment: Even if I enclose it in function Authentication(e), it has stopped giving that error but it is not saving the data in the google sheet

Comment: Please help to solve